# SSO SAML + Embedded Login

Tags: single-sign-on, login, embedded

I'm not finding useful documentation for this scenario

1. Salesforce is set as IDP (identity provider)
2. There are some SP (Service providers, web app)
3. Is implemented a SSO using SAML
4. Is asked to implement login embedded to handle login process in the SP apps

I don't find documentation if the embedded login component

- is "integrated/integrable" with the SSO-SAML infrastructure, the login process handled by the embedded login component is able to perform the the Login process requested by SAML protocol
- if the user has already made login on SP1, and the user is sent to SP2, the embedded login "understand" that the user is already logged in?
- If not, there is anyway to "say" to the embedded login component, that the user is already logged in?

The request comes from the UX perspective, where is tried to avoid the need for the user handle a redirect for the first login.

Comment: Embedded login uses [OpenID Connect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_step_2.htm), it does not use or support SAML.

Comment: @identigral i approved wrongly the below answer. Please transform your comment in answer so i can accept it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation, it does seem as though SAML is supported as long as it is configured in the Connected App (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_authorize_web_app.htm). As for staying logged in, I would imagine a cookie gets stored after the login process takes place that should persist going through different SP's as long as they are registered correctly the SF environment.